How to skew shapes on both sides in isolated mode?
I forgot the shortcut used to shew shapes on both sides in isolated mode. I cant find the a YouTube video since I forgot to bookmark it. I think the shortcut may have involved the key 'alt'

Isolation mode doesn't really matter... This works regardless of Isolation Mode.
Grab the Free Transform Tool (just tap the e key), hold down the Command/Ctrl+Option/Alt keys, grab one of the middle handles on any side and drag - the shape will skew from center.
Of course, when you select the Free Transform tool, there's also that (annoying) popup tool bar with a skew tool on it. If you use that, you just need to hold the Option/Alt key down to skew from center.
